# Caps+Shift+hjkl as arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, remapping, xmodmap, xbindkeys

I currently map caps to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> using the following .Xmodmap:

```
clear lock
clear control
keycode 66 = Control_L
add control = Control_L Control_R
```

I'd like to additionally map <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>HJKL</kbd> to be alternate arrow keys.  Is this possible?  I'm willing to use something fancier like xbindkeys if it would help, but I can't figure out how to do this.  (The basic problem is I am not sure how to handle commands with two modifier keys.)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux (up-to-date arch)